# ¿Como puedo pasar dos argumentos con props en React?

Tags: reactjs, entrada

Hola soy nuevo en esto de `React` pero tengo una duda con los parámetros, solo quiero quiero imprimir nombre y edad en cuanto el `input` cambie de estado, al ingresar la edad en el segundo `input` modifica el nombre y no la edad, porque me sucede esto ? O como puedo agregar el segundo parámetro al `Header`.

**Quisiera algo parecido a esto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Mensaje extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {name: ''}; this.state = {edad:''};
  this.cambioNombre = this.cambioNombre.bind(this);
  this.cambioEdad = this.cambioEdad.bind(this);
  }
  cambioNombre(name) {this.setState({name}); }
  cambioEdad(edad) {this.setState({edad}); }
    render () { return ( <div>
        <Header name={this.state.name} />
       <Input cambioNombre={this.cambioNombre} cambioEdad={this.cambioEdad}/>
   </div> );
  }
}
const Header = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="hi">
      <h3>Hello, {props.name || "visitor"}, tu edad es {props.edad || "100 años"}!</h3>
    </div>
  );   
}
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor() {super(); this.state = {input:''} }
  nombreChange(e) {const name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({input:name});
    this.props.cambioNombre(name); }


  render() {
    return(<div>

      <input placeholder='introduce tu nombre' type='text'
      name={this.state.name} onChange={this.nombreChange.bind(this)}>
      </input>
      <br></br>
      <input placeholder='introduce tu edad' type='text'
      name={this.state.name} onChange={this.nombreChange.bind(this)}>
      </input>

    </div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el componente Mensaje estás defininiendo 2 veces state! Y además tampoco estas pasando la edad al Header.

Esto sería más válido:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name: '', 
    edad: ''
  };

  this.cambioNombre = this.cambioNombre.bind(this);
  this.cambioEdad = this.cambioEdad.bind(this);
}

render() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Header name={this.state.name} edad={this.state.edad} />
      <Input cambioNombre={this.cambioNombre} cambioEdad={this.cambioEdad}/>
    </div> 
  );
}
```

O directamente pasas todo el objecto state al hijo

```
<Header info={this.state} />
```